# how does Civi determine # of installments left in recurring series? (and when it's complete)

Tags: recurring-contributions

We have the amount, frequency, installments, and status on the recurring contribution with a next contribution date. What determines or sets that a profile is complete? If the amount is $5, the frequency is weekly, and the installments are 4 - how does it track that the installments are completed? Can someone point me to the desired functionality as well as a code/database reference (pretty please). My guess is I'm missing something, or somewhere it just counts 4 contributions that are linked and some process marks it as completed. Thank you!

backstory - we are trying to fix some funky stuff, so I need the ins-and-outs of how this works. D7/CiviCRM 5